# drop down menu bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

im trying to create a dropdown button using bootstrap. But it just does not show the list:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    Action
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">sad</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Bootstrap and css files:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>styles/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Thanks

Comment: DO you have bootstrap js included?

Comment: Ok, I added this:
.
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>../../js/bootstrap" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>../../js/bootstrap.min" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: still not working? You need to include jquery too before BS js.

Comment: `<link href="../../js/bootstrap.js" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <link href="../../js/bootstrap.min.js" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Dont works in same

Comment: That is wrong js is not css. try this  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/bootstrap.js">

Comment: Right right, my bad! Distraction... WORKS! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways that dont work well. You can visit and try implementing the code as in *http://jsfprimefacesblog.blogspot.com/2012/05/bootstrap-multilevel-dropdown-menu.html*